# D3 hierarchical bar chart - Rotate X and Y Axes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, hierarchical

I saw an example of a hierarchical bar chart and got it working for my dataset also.

http://d3-example.herokuapp.com/examples/bar/bar-hierarchy.html

However, I would like to have the x and Y axes switched. Basically, would like to see a vertical Bar Chart with hierarchical data. Please Help!

Cheers,
Arjun

Answer (score 2):

here i have solved your issue kindly review my 
 code 
and you will get the solution.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

rect.background {
  fill: white;
}

.axis {
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 10, right: 120, bottom: 120, left: 120},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var barHeight = 20;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["steelblue", "#ccc"]);

var duration = 750,
    delay = 25;

var partition = d3.layout.partition()
    .value(function(d) { return d.size; });

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "background")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .on("click", up);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + height + ")")
    .append("line")
    .attr("x1", "100%");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis");

d3.json("https://jsonblob.com/api/f577d19c-0f2b-11e7-a0ba-09040711ce47", function(error, root) {
  if (error) throw error;

  partition.nodes(root);
  y.domain([0, root.value]).nice();
  down(root, 0);
});

function down(d, i) {
  if (!d.children || this.__transition__) return;
  var end = duration + d.children.length * delay;

  // Mark any currently-displayed bars as exiting.
  var exit = svg.selectAll(".enter")
      .attr("class", "exit");

  // Entering nodes immediately obscure the clicked-on bar, so hide it.
  exit.selectAll("rect").filter(function(p) { return p === d; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Enter the new bars for the clicked-on data.
  // Per above, entering bars are immediately visible.
  var enter = bar(d)
      .attr("transform", stack(i))
      .style("opacity", 1);

  // Have the text fade-in, even though the bars are visible.
  // Color the bars as parents; they will fade to children if appropriate.
  enter.select("text").style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
  enter.select("rect").style("fill", color(true));

  // Update the x-scale domain.
  y.domain([0, d3.max(d.children, function(d) { return d.value; })]).nice();

  // Update the x-axis.
  svg.selectAll(".y.axis").transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .call(yAxis);

  // Transition entering bars to their new position.
  var enterTransition = enter.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .delay(function(d, i) { return i * delay; })
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + barHeight * i * 2.5 + "," + 0 + ")"; });

  // Transition entering text.
  enterTransition.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition entering rects to the new y-scale.
  enterTransition.select("rect")
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(!!d.children); });

  // Transition exiting bars to fade out.
  var exitTransition = exit.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .style("opacity", 1e-6)
      .remove();

  // Transition exiting bars to the new y-scale.
  exitTransition.selectAll("rect")
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });

  // Rebind the current node to the background.
  svg.select(".background")
      .datum(d)
    .transition()
      .duration(end);

  d.index = i;
}

function up(d) {
  if (!d.parent || this.__transition__) return;
  var end = duration + d.children.length * delay;

  // Mark any currently-displayed bars as exiting.
  var exit = svg.selectAll(".enter")
      .attr("class", "exit");

  // Enter the new bars for the clicked-on data's parent.
  var enter = bar(d.parent)
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + barHeight * i * 2.5 + "," + 0 + ")"; })
      .style("opacity", 1e-6);

  // Color the bars as appropriate.
  // Exiting nodes will obscure the parent bar, so hide it.
  enter.select("rect")
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(!!d.children); })
    .filter(function(p) { return p === d; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the y-scale domain.
  y.domain([0, d3.max(d.parent.children, function(d) { return d.value; })]).nice();

  // Update the y-axis.
  svg.selectAll(".y.axis").transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .call(yAxis);

  // Transition entering bars to fade in over the full duration.
  var enterTransition = enter.transition()
      .duration(end)
      .style("opacity", 1);

  // Transition entering rects to the new y-scale.
  // When the entering parent rect is done, make it visible!
  enterTransition.select("rect")
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .each("end", function(p) { if (p === d) d3.select(this).style("fill-opacity", null); });

  // Transition exiting bars to the parent's position.
  var exitTransition = exit.selectAll("g").transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .delay(function(d, i) { return i * delay; })
      .attr("transform", stack(d.index));

  // Transition exiting text to fade out.
  exitTransition.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition exiting rects to the new scale and fade to parent color.
  exitTransition.select("rect")
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .style("fill", color(true));

  // Remove exiting nodes when the last child has finished transitioning.
  exit.transition()
      .duration(end)
      .remove();

  // Rebind the current parent to the background.
  svg.select(".background")
      .datum(d.parent)
    .transition()
      .duration(end);
}

// Creates a set of bars for the given data node, at the specified index.
function bar(d) {
  var bar = svg.insert("g", ".x.axis")
      .attr("class", "enter")
      .attr("transform", "translate(15,0)")
    .selectAll("g")
      .data(d.children)
    .enter().append("g")
      .style("cursor", function(d) { return !d.children ? null : "pointer"; })
      .on("click", down);

  bar.append("text")
      .attr("x", barHeight / 2)
      .attr("y", height + 10)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "start")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .attr("transform", "rotate(45 " + (barHeight / 2) + " " + (height + 10) + ")")

  bar.append("rect")
      .attr("width", barHeight)
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); });

  return bar;
}

// A stateful closure for stacking bars horizontally.
function stack(i) {
  var y0 = 0;
  return function(d) {
    var tx = "translate(" + barHeight * i * 1.5 + "," + y0 + ")";
    y0 += y(d.value);
    return tx;
  };
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite right.. but it's half way there.. the animations don't really work as nicely as the horizontal bar and the drill up completely doesn't work.. hoping someone can help add to it..

```
var m = [40, 50, 5, 70], // top right bottom left
w = 550 - m[1] - m[3], // width
h = 384 - m[0] - m[2], // height
y = d3.scale.linear().range([h,0]),
x = 70, // bar width
z = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["steelblue", "#aaa"]); // bar color

var hierarchy = d3.layout.partition()
    .value(function(d) { return d.size; });

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");


var svg = d3.select(".sales-pipeline-chart").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", w + m[1] + m[3])
    .attr("height", h + m[0] + m[2])
  .append("svg:g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + m[0] + ")");

svg.append("svg:rect")
    .attr("class", "background")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h)
    .on("click", up);

svg.append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "x axis");

svg.append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "y axis");
  /*.append("svg:line")
    .attr("y1", "100%");*/

d3.json("/flare.json", function(root) {
  hierarchy.nodes(root);
  y.domain([0,root.value]).nice();
  down(root, 0);
});

function down(d, i) {

  if (!d.children || this.__transition__) return;
  var duration = d3.event && d3.event.altKey ? 7500 : 750,
      delay = duration / d.children.length;

  // Mark any currently-displayed bars as exiting.
  var exit = svg.selectAll(".enter").attr("class", "exit");

  // Entering nodes immediately obscure the clicked-on bar, so hide it.
  exit.selectAll("rect").filter(function(p) { return p === d; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Enter the new bars for the clicked-on data.
  // Per above, entering bars are immediately visible.
    //var barWidth = w / d.children.length;

  var enter = bar(d)
      .attr("transform", stack(i))
      .style("opacity", 1);

  // Have the text fade-in, even though the bars are visible.
  // Color the bars as parents; they will fade to children if appropriate.
  enter.select("text").style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
  enter.select("rect").style("fill", z(true));

  // Update the y-scale domain.
  y.domain([0, d3.max(d.children, function(d) { return d.value; })]).nice();

  // Update the y-axis.
  svg.selectAll(".y.axis").transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .call(yAxis);  

  // Transition entering bars to their new position.
  var enterTransition = enter.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .delay(function(d, i) { return i * delay; })
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + x * i * 1.3 + "," + (h - y(d.value)) + ")"; });
      /*.call(xAxis);*/

  // Transition entering text.
  enterTransition.select("text").style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition entering rects to the new x-scale.
  enterTransition.select("rect")
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return z(!!d.children); });

  // Transition exiting bars to fade out.
  var exitTransition = exit.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .style("opacity", 1e-6)
      .remove();

  // Transition exiting bars to the new x-scale.
  exitTransition.selectAll("rect").attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.value); });

  // Rebind the current node to the background.
  svg.select(".background").data([d]).transition().duration(duration * 2); d.index = i;
}

function up(d) {
  if (!d.parent || this.__transition__) return;
  var duration = d3.event && d3.event.altKey ? 7500 : 750,
      delay = duration / d.children.length;

  // Mark any currently-displayed bars as exiting.
  var exit = svg.selectAll(".enter").attr("class", "exit");

  // Enter the new bars for the clicked-on data's parent.
  var enter = bar(d.parent)
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + x * i * 1.3 + "," + (h - y(d.value)) + ")"; })
      .style("opacity", 1e-6);

  // Color the bars as appropriate.
  // Exiting nodes will obscure the parent bar, so hide it.
  enter.select("rect")
      .style("fill", function(d) { return z(!!d.children); })
    .filter(function(p) { return p === d; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the x-scale domain.
  y.domain([0, d3.max(d.parent.children, function(d) { return d.value; })]).nice();

  // Update the x-axis.
  svg.selectAll(".y.axis").transition()
      .duration(duration * 2)
      .call(yAxis);

  // Transition entering bars to fade in over the full duration.
  var enterTransition = enter.transition()
      .duration(duration * 2)
      .style("opacity", 1);

  // Transition entering rects to the new x-scale.
  // When the entering parent rect is done, make it visible!
  enterTransition.select("rect")
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .each("end", function(p) { if (p === d) d3.select(this).style("fill-opacity", null); });

  // Transition exiting bars to the parent's position.
  var exitTransition = exit.selectAll("g").transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .delay(function(d, i) { return i * delay; })
      .attr("transform", stack(d.index));

  // Transition exiting text to fade out.
  exitTransition.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition exiting rects to the new scale and fade to parent color.
  exitTransition.select("rect")
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .style("fill", z(true));

  // Remove exiting nodes when the last child has finished transitioning.
  exit.transition().duration(duration * 2).remove();

  // Rebind the current parent to the background.
  svg.select(".background").data([d.parent]).transition().duration(duration * 2);
}

// Creates a set of bars for the given data node, at the specified index.
function bar(d) {
  var bar = svg.insert("svg:g", ".x.axis")
      .attr("class", "enter")
      .attr("transform", "translate(10,0)")
    .selectAll("g")
      .data(d.children)
    .enter().append("svg:g")
      .style("cursor", function(d) { return !d.children ? null : "pointer"; })
      .on("click", down);

  bar.append("svg:text")
      .attr("y", -6)
      .attr("x", x / 2)
      //.attr("dx", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  /*var barWidth = w / d.children.length;*/

  bar.append("svg:rect")
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("width", x/*barWidth*/);

  return bar;
}

// A stateful closure for stacking bars horizontally.
function stack(i) {
  var y0 = 0;
  return function(d) {
    var ty = "translate(" + x * i * 1.2 + "," + y0 + ")";
    y0 += y(d.value);
    return ty;
  };
}
```